# Link to Case from SearchKit Table Display

Tags: civicase, searchkit

I'd like to build a report in SearchKit/Afform to replace the default Case tab so that I can organize cases by type a bit better but I can't figure out how to add a link to open the case in the table display.

What should I be looking into to learn how to make that link? Screenshot included below of the specific spot I'd like to add that link to "Manage Case" or "View Case" or something along those lines.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would just do this in the display and make the case id field itself a link to `civicrm/contact/view/case?action=view&reset=1&id=[id]&cid=[Case_CaseContact_Contact_01.id]`. The tokens would depend on your search joins - you'll find them in the `</>` dropdown. The above assumes cases are the main entity, joined to case-clients.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try that!

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!